# UITextView to Mimic UITextField [for basic round corner text field]

Tags: colors, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to have UITextField with multiple lines, after a quick google on this issue I found that I should use TextView so I did switch my code to use UITextView when I want multiple lines. My View still have other one line textField that I want to keep.

To make my TextView looks like TextField, I had to add code to set border and radius, but they look a little bit different on iOS7. Does anyone know:

- what is the color for the UITextField border? when both enabled and disabled so I can sent my textview to match it.
- what is radius of the corner of TextField.
- what is the background color for UITextField when it is disabled[attached picture shows the text field has lighter shade of grey when it is disabled]? so i can set my text view to the same color when i disable user interaction.

If there is away to keep using textfield for multiline text, I am all ears and i switch to use it.

Best Regards,

[image]

Comment: anyone on this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use a single line UITextView instead of the UITextField. This way you can customise them both to look the same.

Answer (score 7):

I use this:

```
textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:215.0 / 255.0 green:215.0 / 255.0 blue:215.0 / 255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.6f;
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
```

little differences in the params make it looks more like UITextField(I hope).

Comment: This looks much more accurate on a retina display.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

-(void) textViewLikeTextField:(UITextView*)textView
{
    [textView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:212.0/255.0
                                                                       green:212.0/255.0
                                                                        blue:212.0/255.0
                                                                       alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [textView.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

and get a good resut.

Comment: I used this but with @Hamhog's modifications below which are a little more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small subclass of UITextView that gives in iOS 7 the same look as the UITextField

The interface is empty:

```
@interface MyTextView : UITextView
@end
```

The implementation overwrites the initialization and the setter of the 'editable' property:

```
@implementation MyTextView

//================================================================================

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

//================================================================================

- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

//================================================================================

- (void) commonInit
{
    self.layer.borderWidth  = 1.0f;
    self.layer.borderColor  = [[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0/255.0
                       green:232.0/255.0 blue:232.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
}

//================================================================================

- (void) setEditable: (BOOL) editable
{
    [super setEditable:editable];

    if (editable)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0/255.0
                                green:250.0/255.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
}

//================================================================================

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got with enabled UITextView

```
[yourTextView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2] CGColor]];
[yourTextView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
yourTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
yourTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
yourTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```